# Using regex to match multiple optional arguments in an enclosed custom function

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-group

I'm building a website and I have created a couple of custom functions that add certain information on the page. One of them is as follows:

`{{i|Custom argument 1|Custom argument 2|Custom argument 3|...|Custom argument n}}`

The number of arguments has no limit, and they all follow the same pattern, starting with `|`, and finishing with another `|`, or `}}` for the last argument.

I'm trying to capture all custom arguments with a RegEx pattern, and them use `preg_replace_callback` to make the replacements.

I managed to create a RegEx pattern that works with 1 optional argument, but I can't manage to add more. A single pattern to capture all arguments as groups would be the best scenario.

Thanks!

This is my current code that works with 1 mandatory `$match[1]` and 1 optional argument `$match[2]`.
I'm trying to get the 2nd optional argument `$match[3]` to work.

```php
$text = preg_replace_callback("{{{i\|(.*?)(?:\|(.*?))?}}}", 
function($match)
{
    return '<a href="some_link/'. $match[1] .'><img src="img_dir/'. $match[2] .'.png">'. (isset($match[3]) ? $match[3] : "Default text") .'</a>';
}, $text);
```

Comment: Why don't you first capture what is between `{{....}}` and then split on a pipe char?

Comment: That's actually a very smart and simple workaround, and I can even use it to combine all my separate patterns in one. Much appreciated!